# I need to default dates in two date textboxes to specify date ranges from and to dates

Tags: c#

I need to get the last saturday and previous sunday of last saturday based on current date (for e.g. if todays is 5/21/2014 i need to get 5/17/2014(saturday) and 5/11/2014(sunday) )and if today is saturday then it should be today's date and last sunday (for e.g. if today is 5/24/2014 i should be getting 5/18/2014)

here's what i am trying to accomplish but its not giving me correct output

```
            DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Today;
            int offset = currentDate.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Sunday;
            offset = (offset < 0) ? 6 : offset;
            string strCulture =  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;

            if (currentDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            {
                txtStartDate.Text = strCulture == "en-US" ? currentDate.AddDays(-offset).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") : currentDate.AddDays(-offset).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") ;
                txtEndDate.Text = strCulture == "en-US" ? currentDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") : currentDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            }
            else
            {
                offset = currentDate.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Saturday;
                offset = (offset < 0) ? 6 : offset;
                DateTime lastSaturday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-offset);
                offset = lastSaturday.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Sunday;
                offset = (offset < 0) ? 6 : offset;
                DateTime lastSunday = lastSaturday.AddDays(-offset);
                txtStartDate.Text = strCulture == "en-US"? lastSunday.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"):lastSunday.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                txtEndDate.Text = strCulture == "en-US" ? lastSaturday.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") : lastSaturday.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the day of the week with DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.
Then get to the previous Sunday by substracting a number of days equal to that day, because Sunday has a value of 0.

```
int days = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
DateTime lastSunday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-days);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
DateTime lastSaturday, lastSunday;
if(today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
{
    lastSaturday = today;        
}
else
{
    int offset = today.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday;

    var moday = today.AddDays(-offset);// Monday of current week
    lastSaturday = monday.AddDays(-2);
}
lastSunday = lastSaturday.AddDays(-6);
```

Comment: Hi Sultan thanks for the code but i didnt understand why finding the Monday of the week

Comment: What if today is monday then offest becomes 0 and last saturday will be 19th instead of 17th

Comment: If you can find the current Monday, you can find the last Saturday and Sunday arithmetically. By the way, Asia's first day of the week is Monday. :)

Comment: thanks for the explanation Sultan but i need to find the last sunday even the above code there are some issues like what if today is monday or sunday then the last saturday gets the wrong date as mentioned above event if today's sunday then again the offset becomes -1 and last saturday is getting wrong date

Comment: I just tested it and works fine, but, Yes, the problem with Sunday